# Anti XSS code encapsulated inside model class, does it belong there?

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I had some XSS protection code I wanted to add into my Web API/MVC application, the model that was used to bind was `EditLocationViewModel` as below.
My initial plan was to add `safeName = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(locationName, false)` into the controller but that would leave the controller littered with `AntiXssEncoder` code. I figured it could be encapsulated better within the model class, see `UpdateLocationViewModel`.

I have a small voice saying to me that the XSS code is more than just validation so perhaps should not be on the model class but in fact back in the controller.

Which would be the better approach?
Any other changes that would be recommended?

Before changes...

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class EditLocationViewModel
    {
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Location name.")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Location name has exceeded the maximum length of 50 characters.")]
        public string NewLocationName { get; set; }
        public string NewAddress { get; set; }
        public string NewPhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string NewFaxNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After changes...

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Security.AntiXss;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public class UpdateLocationViewModel
    {
        private string locationName;
        private string address;
        private string phoneNumber;
        private string fax;

        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Location name.")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Location name has exceeded the maximum length of 50 characters.")]
        public string LocationName
        {
            get { return AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(locationName, false); }
            set { locationName = value.Trim(); }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get { return AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(address, false); }
            set { address = value?.Trim(); }
        }
        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get { return AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(phoneNumber, false); }
            set { phoneNumber = value?.Trim(); }
        }
        public string FaxNumber
        {
            get { return AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(fax, false); }
            set { fax = value?.Trim(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a model. It's a view model. So it's perfectly valid to have some presentation concerns her. i.e. XSS protection

Comment: That was my thinking, nice to have it seconded